# Fade in and pulse text, delay then fade out with CSS3 animation?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadein, pulse

I've been trying to create an effect on a piece of text in my website but not having much luck. I was hoping to create it with CSS but if anyone can suggest a way with jQuery too then I'll try anything.

I basically want to fade the  in, then as it fades in it pulses then it delays for a certain length of time and then fades out. I want this to happen on a loop.

I have a slideshow and I basically want each  of the four slides/titles to fade in over each corresponding slide which is currently set up on a loop with keyframes. I need to be able to put each title in with the slide it goes with.

For example:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>
         <h2 class="title1">Title One</h2>
         <img src="../" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h2 class="title1">Title Two</h2>
         <img src="../" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h2 class="title1">Title Three</h2>
         <img src="../" />
      </li>
      <li>
         <h2 class="title1">Title Four</h2>
         <img src="../" />
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try to use Animate.css - https://github.com/daneden/animate.css

```
$('.title1').addClass('animated pulse');

$('.title1').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', doSomething);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion, I had seen this but wasn't sure how I could apply this for each one?

Comment: That seems to have worked although I am stuck as to how I would set this on a loop so that each one fires the animation when its supposed to?

Comment: Also because I have the type i want to pop in centered for some reason the animation is knocking the position off?  http://jsfiddle.net/86KLb/2/

Answer (score 0):

A JQuery solution as you requested..

http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/9N5Aa/2/

```
doEffect($('li'));


function doEffect(ctrl){

 $(ctrl).fadeIn(500, function() {
   ctrl.effect( "pulsate", 5000 ).fadeOut(500);
   doEffect(ctrl);
  });
 }
```

Comment: Is there any way it could look more like this minus the fact its jumping out of position when it shouldn't be? http://jsfiddle.net/86KLb/3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/4/ you were missing `position relative` on the container. @user2498890

Comment: Ah i see thanks, do you have any idea how I could apply this to all 4 titles and set them as a loop - maybe with query?

Comment: one after another or all at once? @user2498890

Comment: would you mind just demonstrating that I'm trying but can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/5/ @user2498890  This along the lines of what youre looking for?

Comment: Yes that is however I would need it to keep doing it as it will be part of a slide show thats on an infinite loop? Many thanks for your help so far.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/86KLb/6/ @user2498890  Hows that? Give me more information about when to trigger + what to do.

Comment: Thats more along the lines of what I want it to do, I need it to be delayed for say 6s before it fades out then a second delay before it fades in again to allow time for change of slides? Thanks so much for this! - It needs to do what it does the first 2 times for 4 times one for each slide and then just continue on a loop as the carousel goes roudn

Comment: can you use this method?? http://jsfiddle.net/jFIT/9N5Aa/3/ not able to do it with the CSS :/ you can mess with the numbers a bit for timing.

Comment: I prefer the CSS look but thanks for all your help :)

Comment: No worries you've helped me a lot.